# ObjectSet.Context vs DbSet

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

i used to use the `ObjectSet` in EF 4.0, I could get the underlying **Context** for this `ObjectSet` using

`myObjectSet.Context` which returns  `ObjectContext`.

Now with `DbSet` in Ef4.1, what is the equivalent ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get the DbContext from a DbSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710769/can-you-get-the-dbcontext-from-a-dbset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF 4.1 does not offer a public API to get the `DbContext` from the `DbSet` instance. You would have to use Reflections API to get the `DbContext` instance.

**Edit**

One workaround would be to pass around the `DbContext` instace with `DbSet` instance.
Eg if you had a constructor that took only a `DbSet` instance. Pass the `DbContext` instace also.

```
public MyService(DbContext context, DbSet<MyClass> mySet){}
```

Other method would be to open up the `EntityFramewrk.dll` inside [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) and find out how to get the `DbContext` instace by accessing the **internal/private** fields of `DbSet`. I wouldn't advice you to use this because implementations can change.

Comment: could you please guide me through ?

Comment: I mean, I cannot find any direct relation between DbSet and DbContext

Comment: @Mustafa You have to ask ADO.NET team why they did not expose that :) Edited my answer to add workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Eranga you are right, i guess they will do it in up coming version :)