# DbSet - Accessing Context

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ObjectSet.Context vs DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198023/objectset-context-vs-dbset)

From a DbSet in EF code first, is there a way to refer to the parent DbContext?  On the ObjectSet, there is an ObjectContext property.  Does something like this exist for the DbSet, or some other means to get the context?

Comment: I am interested in understanding the scenario here. Can you elaborate a bit more why you need it?

Comment: It's part of my architecture; I created some architecture around the ObjectSet, and I was going to do the same with the DbSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some digging; internally, it does keep track of this association, through an array of internal objects.  So it's not public, and therefore best to pass the DbContext with the DbSet as another parameter.